# Single-entry implementation gone wrong

Tags: php, implementation

I'm doing my first single-entry site and based on the result, I can't see the benefit.

I've implemented the following:

- .htaccess redirects all requests to index.php at the root
- Url is parsed and each /segment/ is stored as an element in an array
- First segment indicates which folder to include (e.g. "users" » "/pages/users/index.php").
- index.php file of each folder parses the remaining elements in the segments array until array is empty.
- content.php file of each folder is included if there are no more elements in the segments array, indicating that the destination file is reached

**Sample**

File structure ( folders in [] ):

- *[root]*

  - index.php
  - *[pages]*

    - *[users]*

      - index.php
      - content.php
      - *[profile]*

        - index.php
        - content.php
        - *[edit]*

          - index.php
          - content.php
    - *[other-page]*

      - index.php
      - content.php

Request: **http://mysite.com/users/profile/**

1. .htaccess redirects request to http://mysite.com/index.php
2. URL is parsed and segments array contains: [1] users, [2] profile
3. index.php maps [1] to "pages/users/index.php", so includes that file
4. pages/users/index.php maps [2] to pages/users/profile/index.php, so includes that file
5. Since no other elements in the segments array, the contents.php file in the current folder (pages/users/profile) is included.

---

I'm not really seeing the benefit of doing this over having functions that include components of the site (e.g. include_header(), include_footer(), etc.), so I conclude that I'm doing something terribly wrong. I'm just not sure what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version you have is lacking some functions and only works as a very simplistic front-controller pattern.

Most systems don't map the URL to a single PHP file that *is the page* - they map the URL path to a controller that knows how to *build the page*.

In addition, not all URL's need to map to a direct file. For example, look at `github.com/[username]/[repo]`. You can't create millions of `bob/ajaxstuff/index.php` files - you need to use regex to tell a controller you want the write page for this project.

```
$app->get('/:username/:repo', function ($username, $repo) {
    echo "Looking at $username's $repo";
});
```

To really grasp how this should be used correctly I recommend you use a full-featured routing system like the simple [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/).

If you want more information about routing design and theory I recommend reading [php-router's](https://github.com/robap/php-router) readme and the excellent [URL Design](http://warpspire.com/posts/url-design/) post from warpspire.

If any of those are too much, you can also look at [klein](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php) and the super-simple [ToroPHP](http://toroweb.org/) library.

Answer (score 2):

That’s because you’d normally use this approach when your content is stored in a database, rather than a file-based system like you have. If your pages are standalone files then re-writing is unnecessary.